# FlatList is not re-rendering on the state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

On pressing the button(ButtonComponent), the state of the button gets changed. Now I'm passing that state to the `<FlatListItem>` (a child component ) inside `<FlatList>`. Depending on that status, the each item in the `<FlatList>` should be re-arranged.

I just got to know about this extraData prop but not sure how to make use of it in the code.

It's not something new but it is like simple checkbox implementation.
Everything is working fine but when I press the select all button all the remaining select buttons are not getting toggled to selected.

[image: image-1]

[image: image-2]

```
class FlatListItem extends Component{  
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    const{ isSelected }=this.props
    this.state={
        selectedStatus:isSelected,
    }
}

changeSelectStatus=(key)=>{
    this.setState({selectedStatus:!this.state.selectedStatus});
    return key;
}

render(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1,
            flexDirection:'row',
            backgroundColor:'white'}}>
            <View>
                <Image
                    source={{uri:this.props.item.imageUri}}
                    style={{width:50, height:50, margin:5}}>
                </Image>
            </View>
            <View>
                <Text style={{color:'black', padding:10, fontSize:16}}>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'flex-end', paddingRight:-10}}>
                {this.state.selectedStatus?
                    **<ButtonComponent buttonColor={"black"} buttonTextColor={"white"} fullRounded={true}
                    borderHighlight={true} buttonWidth={70} buttonHeight={30} 
                    onPress={()=>this.props.showSelected(this.changeSelectStatus(this.props.item.key)) }>
                        Selected
                    </ButtonComponent>
                :
                    <ButtonComponent buttonColor={"white"} buttonTextColor={"black"} fullRounded={true}
                    borderHighlight={true} buttonWidth={70} buttonHeight={30} 
                    onPress={()=>this.props.showSelected(this.changeSelectStatus(this.props.item.key)) }>
                        Select
                    </ButtonComponent>
                }                    
            </View>
        </View>
    )
 }

  }
export default class SelectMembersBody extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        selectedButtons:[],
        selectAllBtnStatus:false,
    }
}
selectAllMembers=()=>{
    let allMembers=[];
    if(!this.state.selectAllBtnStatus){
        membersData.forEach(element => {
            if(!this.state.selectedButtons.includes(element.key))
                allMembers.push(element.key)                
        });
        this.setState({
            selectAllBtnStatus:!this.state.selectAllBtnStatus,
            selectedButtons:[...this.state.selectedButtons, allMembers]
        })
    }
    else{
        this.setState({
            selectAllBtnStatus:!this.state.selectAllBtnStatus,
            selectedButtons:[...allMembers]
        })
    }
}
showSelected=(callback)=>{
    let val = callback;
    if(!this.state.selectedButtons.includes(val))
        this.setState({selectedButtons:[...this.state.selectedButtons, val]});
    else{
        let newMarkers=[...this.state.selectedButtons]
        let index = newMarkers.indexOf(val);
        if (index >= 0) {
            newMarkers.splice( index, 1 );
        }
        this.setState({selectedButtons:newMarkers});
    }
}
render(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1, }}>
            <Text>{this.state.selectedButtons}</Text>
            <View>
                {this.state.selectAllBtnStatus?
                    <ButtonComponent buttonColor={"black"} buttonTextColor={"white"} fullRounded={true}
                        borderHighlight={true} buttonWidth={85} buttonHeight={30} onPress={this.selectAllMembers}>
                            Selected All
                    </ButtonComponent> 
                :
                    <ButtonComponent buttonColor={"white"} buttonTextColor={"black"} fullRounded={true}
                        borderHighlight={true} buttonWidth={85} buttonHeight={30} onPress={this.selectAllMembers}>
                            Select All
                    </ButtonComponent> }
            </View>                
            <FlatList data={membersData} extraData={this.state}
                renderItem={({item, index})=>{
                    return(
                        <View>
                            <FlatListItem item={item} index={index} isSelected={this.state.selectAllBtnStatus} showSelected={this.showSelected} ></FlatListItem>
                        </View>
                    )
                }
            }></FlatList>       
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: show us whats inside selectAllMembers function

Comment: re-arrange FlatList  to what?

Comment: @JojoNarte Please find my entire code now.

Comment: @Afaq there is a button in each of my flatlist items. Depending on this buttoncomponent status in the parent the status of the button in the child(flatlistitem) gets changed.

Answer (score 2):

I know that it's quite harder to step into someone's shoes. The code I provided in my question might not be that effective since I'm a learner. That's why it is uncomfortable to get on to the code flow. So, I decided to answer my own question after reading some articles, docs and similar questions on StackOverFlow.

So, my question is why the flatlist was not getting re-rendered on setState. To be more precise, if you've gone through the pictures above, on selecting the Select All button all the buttons in the items should be toggled to selected state.

To make the flatlist re-render, we need to add an additional prop **"extraData"**

> By passing extraData={this.state} to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state.selected changes. Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes.

You can get it's full [documentation here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata).

In my case, I set extraData = {this.state} since the status of buttons in each of the flatlist item depends on the array which is present in the parent component. 
So, I've sent it to child component via props.

Now the flatlist is working fine and re-rendering on every state update.

Comment: Thanx man, saved us time